# Magento1.9 : How can I GetWebProducts using Soap Api?

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v2, web-services

I have this type of WebService

[image]

How can I get products detail using Magento 1.9, kindly explain me in detail that how can I get data using this Webservice. If someone can list down the step how can I achieve this.

Really appreciate for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow steps below carefully to call magento API

**step 1: Create SOAP Role from Admin Panel**

1) Please go to System -> Web Service -> SOAP/XML-RPC -Roles

2) Click "Add New Role".

3) Enter Role name (like "api_user") and enter admin password

4) Select Role Resources. You can select All or Custom depending 
on your needs.

5) Click "Save Role" button.

[image]

**step 2: Create SOAP User from Admin Panel**

1) Please go to System -> Web Service -> SOAP/XML-RPC -Users

2) click Add New user

3) Please enter all data for new soap user. Make sure you have saved the "User Name" and the "API Key" in a file for feature use in API call.

4) Click "User Role" tab.

5) Select the role to assign to the Soap user

6) click "Save user" button

[image]

**step 3: create a php file , Call the Magento Product details API **

Note: Please change soap user name, API key and Web Url with your data from the php script.

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
const SOAP_API_USER = 'your_soap_user_name';
const SOAP_API_PASS = 'your_soap_api_key';
const SOAP_API_ENDPOINT = 'http://YOURPROJECTWEBURL/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl';

$soapClient = new SoapClient(SOAP_API_ENDPOINT, array('trace' => true,
'keep_alive' => true,
'connection_timeout' => 5000,
'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
'compression' => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP | SOAP_COMPRESSION_DEFLATE,));

$sessionId = $soapClient->login(SOAP_API_USER, SOAP_API_PASS); // apiUser , apiKey        
$productId  = 4; // Product Id to get details
$result = $soapClient->catalogProductInfo($sessionId,$productId);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: in magento where i have to add this type of code to get the products,,
i attached an image:
POST /test/service.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: soap.unze.co.uk
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <GetWebProducts xmlns="fashionmaster">
      <ReturnCol>string</ReturnCol>
    </GetWebProducts>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>

Answer (score 0):

How you see the XML output ? I can see object and array only please guide me how can i see XML format for this API request please urgent